# Creating new column based on values of other column (condition on date present in multiple columns) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

In the dataset, there are several columns with date as value. I need to create new columns based on certain condition on the date values. Certain date values are replaced by "\N" character, so it appears that entire column is being treated as string.

```
Date 1      Date 2
2012-12-03  2012-12-07
2004-12-31  \N
\N          2010-10-20
2014-11-22  \N
2014-12-16  2014-12-31

df = read_csv('filepath')
df['Level'] = np.where(df['Date 1'] - df['Date 2'] > '60', 'Level 1','Level 2')
```

This is giving me an error

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*

Also the condition will include another scenario (the syntax may not be correct)

```
np.where(df['Date 1'] == pd.datetime('YYYY-MM-DD') & df['Date 1'] == "\N", 'Level 1','Level 2')
```

Any direction in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The column is indeed being treated as string. This happens because, by default, pandas doesn't convert values to date types.

After `df = read_csv(path)`, you can do:

```py
df['Date 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 1'], errors='coerce')
df['Date 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2'], errors='coerce')
```

`errors='coerce'` will convert the `'\N'` values to `NaT` (Not a Time), indicating that those dates are not present.

Later on, you can operate on those columns. I don't know exactly what is your intention, but, for example, this will return the difference of `Date1` and `Date2`, in days:

```py
diff = (df['Date1'] - df['Date2']).days
```